# ax 2012 r3 async server installation

Tags: asynchronous

getting error of "There is a problem with windows installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor." while installing async server of ax 2012 r3

Answer (score 1):

The SQLCMD utility is required to install Async Server. This utility is typically installed with Microsoft SQL Server. If a version of SQL Server is not installed on the computer where you install Async Server, you can download and install Microsoft Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server to meet this requirement.

Microsoft ODBS 11 Driver for SQL Server
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Microsoft Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433